# jQuery append with conditions

Tags: jquery

I have a table that is populated by a getJSON call. Is it possible to append the table with a condition? For example, I don't want rows appended if the table row has `true` in the Excluded (4th column). The below snippet is a 100% working getJSON call that populates all data from the manifest.json file.

```
            $.getJSON("/db/manifest.json").then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            var tr = data
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var tr = $('<tr/>');

                $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].id + "</td>");
                $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>");
                $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].reward + "</td>");
                $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].excluded + "</td>");
                $('#user-table').append(tr);
            }

        });
```

Comment: I'd like to add that I have tried adding the below snippet to the end of the script and no luck...

    $("#user-table td:nth-of-type(4):contains('true')").parent ().hide ();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put an `if` condition before doing all your appends.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  if (!data[i].excluded) {
    // Will only execute when excluded is false
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].id + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].reward + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].excluded + "</td>");
    $('#user-table').append(tr);
  }

}
```

Comment: How would that differentiate the Excluded column containing a 'true' or 'false'?

Comment: What i think you want to achieve is to not append row if the excluded is true. Right?

Comment: Yes. And, your answer works and only shows rows with the Excluded column of 'false'. I'm confused what your if statement is looking for through.

Comment: `!data[i].excluded` is checking this condition `data[i].excluded===false`.

Comment: @Mike To break it down `data[i].excluded` evaluates to `true` or `false`.  `!` negates it.